# $\cos 5x − \cos 3x = −8 \sin^2 x(2 \cos^3 x −\cos x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Here's my problem, can someone show me the steps on doing this:

> $$\cos 5x − \cos 3x  =  −8 \sin^2 x(2 \cos^3 x − \cos x)$$

Here is a link to my problem, I don't know what to put into the blanks though

[image]

Comment: Note that $\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*:

- "Double angle identities":

  $$\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$$
  $$\sin 4x = 2\sin 2x \cos 2x$$
  $$\sin 8x = 2\sin 4x \cos 4x$$
  $$\dots$$
- And the final blank is a simple multiplication.